# geom_raster comes out "smeared" when saving to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

When I save a ggplot that uses `geom_raster`, the tiles come out "smeared". It's the same result if I use `ggsave()` or `pdf()`. I don't have this problem with `geom_tile` or `image`. I don't have this problem with the RStudio, X11, or PNG graphics devices.

What's causing this? How can I fix it?

Examples:

```
library(ggplot2)

## doesn't work: tiles are smeared together

ggsave("smeared1.pdf",
  ggplot(cbind(expand.grid(x = 1:3, y = 1:3), fill = rnorm(9))) +
    geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)))

pdf("smeared2.pdf")
ggplot(cbind(expand.grid(x = 1:3, y = 1:3), fill = rnorm(9))) +
    geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill))
dev.off()

## works fine

ggsave("not-smeared0.png",
  ggplot(cbind(expand.grid(x = 1:3, y = 1:3), fill = rnorm(9))) +
    geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)))

ggsave("not-smeared1.pdf",
  ggplot(cbind(expand.grid(x = 1:3, y = 1:3), fill = rnorm(9))) +
    geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)))

pdf("not-smeared2.pdf")
ggplot(cbind(expand.grid(x = 1:3, y = 1:3), fill = rnorm(9))) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)))
dev.off()

pdf("not-smeared3.pdf")
image(matrix(rnorm(9), 3))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Maybe post a screen shot or two so we can easily see what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for this. Chancing `geom_raster` to `geom_tile` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is probably due to your PDF viewer doing [interpolation of the raster](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/8VLuo1cw6SE). I recreated your "smeared2.pdf" on my Mac (see below) and it looked fine in Adobe Reader (right) and blurred in Preview (left). Depending on your PDF viewer, you might be able to get rid of the blurring effect by changing a setting. For example, in Preview, in the PDF tab under Preferences you can uncheck "Smooth Text and Line Art" and the PDF will display properly.

[image]

Comment: I didn't think about using a different reader. Yes, I'm using Preview. Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Comment: Yes. Change Preview's settings as noted in the my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Is it "more portable" to use geom_tile, or is this a setting that people "should" have turned off anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is the first time I've encountered this issue. But then I normally use geom_tile for situations like this and haven't used geom_raster before.