# Why does my plot of a raster in R blur in saved file?

Tags: r, r-raster, r-maptools, rmaps

I'm hoping to export a map with a raster plotted on it as a .pdf or some other vector file. For some reason, when I save it as a .pdf or .ps file, the raster is blurry/fuzzy/smeared and unusable. Any tips for fixing this? A .png saves with the desired resolution, but can't be manipulated layer-by-layer in post-processing.

```
library(maps)
library(raster)

ra<-raster(nrows=40,ncols=35,xmn=-110,xmx=-75,ymn=7,ymx=47)
ra2 <- rasterize(cbind(runif(1000,min=-109,max=-76),runif(1000,min=8,max=46)), ra,fun=function(x,...)log10(length(x)))
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("grey90","grey40"))
map(database="world",regions=c("US","Mexico","El Salvador","Honduras","Costa Rica","Guatemala","Belize","Nicaragua","Panama"),myborder=0.0000001,xlim=c(-110,-75),ylim=c(0,50))
plot(ra2,add=T,col=pal(7))
```

[Here is a screenshot of the saved .pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX7Yb.png)
[Here is a screenshot of the Quartz window with desired resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oaeT.png)

Comment: Possibly related or even a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29568923/2954547

Answer (score 2):

I just found that adding 'useRaster=FALSE' to the plot() function fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to save high-resolution image as pdf file

```
pdf(file = "My Plot.pdf",   
    width = 14, # The width of the plot in inches
    height = 8.5) # The height of the plot in inches

pal <- colorRampPalette(c("grey90","grey40"))
map(database="world",regions=c("US","Mexico","El Salvador","Honduras","Costa Rica","Guatemala","Belize","Nicaragua","Panama"),myborder=0.0000001,xlim=c(-110,-75),ylim=c(0,50))
plot(ra2,add=T,col=pal(7))

#Run dev.off() to create the file!
dev.off()
```

Comment: This (and similarly, postscript()), still produces the same blurry effect.